# How do you compare dates in a LINQ query?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am tring to compare a date from a asp calendar control to a date in the table.... here's what i have... it doesn't like the == ?

```
var query = from details in db.TD_TravelCalendar_Details
                    where details.StartDate == calStartDate.SelectedDate
                    && details.EndDate == calEndDate.SelectedDate
                    select details;
```

Comment: Additional details would be helpful - what error, exactly does it give you? It's hard to infer your types from what you provided.  What type is details.StartDate? And calStartDate.SelectedDate?

Comment: == is fine for comparing date. From your comments, both left and right operands are DateTime, so I'm suspecting that you may have modelled your StartDate or EndDate as allow NULL in DB, in this case it will represent StartDate field as DateTime? rather then DateTime

Answer (score 1):

In order for your query to work both `details.StartDate` and `calStartDate.SelectedDate` must be typed as `System.DateTime`.

What error are you receiving?  Most likely one of these properties is a string and will need to be [parsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) into a `DateTime` instance for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

What is the Type of `details.StartDate` and `details.EndDate`? Is it `String`? Maybe that's the problem. If the database type is `String` you should [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx) the Date String into a `DateTime` and compare it with the calendar's selected date then.